# Which procedure to point to a directory from everywhere in the site

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, point

If I should point to a directory from everywhere in the site which is the best procedure?

```
$folder = "http://www.mysite.com/something/foldertopoint"
```

or

```
$folder = "/WEB/mysite/htdocs/something/foldertopoint"
```

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve, a URL or a file system path?

Comment: This will be included on the header file which will be included everywhere. On this file I will do this: $folder= scandir("/WEB/mysite/htdocs/something/foldertopoint"); (or using the other way). I need that everywhere the header is included this path is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use something like `__DIR__` it is a magical constant. If you define a path in say a config file

Path to config file: `/var/www/include/config.php`

inside you have say

```
define('_INC_', __DIR__);
```

Anywhere you use the constant `_INC_` will always point to `/var/www/include`

so if you are in: `/var/www/some/crazy/path/of/nonsense.php`

You can simply use

```
include(_INC_."/myinclude.php");
```

which will include `/var/www/include/myinclude.php`

saves time when trying to include folers/files site-wide.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you are linking to a file within the directory - go with first one. If you are doing file operations on files inside the directory within your script you'll need to use the second one.

Comment: This will be included on the header file which will be included everywhere. On this file I will do this:
$folder= scandir("/WEB/mysite/htdocs/something/foldertopoint");
(or using the other way). I need that everywhere the header is included this path is working.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `$folder = "/WEB/mysite/htdocs/something/foldertopoint"`

Your code becomes reusable as it is not tied to a specific domain.